# Comparing a string and always getting a true

Tags: iphone

I have some code that gets exicuted if the enter key is press.  If the string in the edit field is null, I want it to exit and do nothing.  It seems like my if then is alwys tru, even if the string is not empty.  I use the debuuger to make sure the string had somethin in it and it did, but the if then still went off.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    gMessage=[ [NSString alloc] initWithString: mMessage.text];
    if ([gMessage compare:@""])
        return YES;    // CODE ALLWYS GOES HERE NO MATTER WHAT gMessage is

    gNextPage=1;
    mMessage.text=@"";


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: `compare` doesn't return a `Boolean` value, `isEqualToString` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I better to check string `length` to make sure that string has no characters.

`compare` method return not `BOOL` value is return enum type `NSComparisonResult` and IMHO it wrong casted to bool inside if statement

To compare strings use `isEqualToString`